# WPF How to zoom figure on a canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, zooming

I am looking for a way to zoom figures (say a polyline) on a canvas without zooming the canvas background image.  I have a solution that zooms figures and the background image at the same time by varying the canvas scaletransform,  now I would like only the figure to zoom. 
Here attached are the example pictures of what I would like to get.

[image before zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCMob.png)

[image after zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XmE8.png)

I have tried to play with Layout transform and vary the transformscale of the figures but it didn't do the trick.
Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Comment: Use a Path control, assign a Geometry to its Data property, and set/update the Transform property of the Geometry.

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand your demand, but does it go like this?

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="backgroundCanvas" />
    <Canvas x:Name="figureCanvas">
      <Canvas.RenderTransform> ...
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Two `Canvas`es are overlaid and then the transform is performed separately.